# File History - How long will a file remain in backup after it is deleted from computer?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

When using File History on Windows 10, and you delete a file from your computer, how long will it remain in the backup folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It remains for as as long as you specify.

As of Windows 10 1607, there are two places in which you can specify this:

**First location:**

- Control Panel

  - *System and Security*

    - File History

      - *Advanced Settings* (on the left pane)

[image: File History preferences in Control Panel]

**Second location:**

- Settings app

  - *Update & security* tile (lower right)

    - *Backup* (on the left pane)

      - *More options* (hyperlink)

[image: File History preferences in Settings]

Your choices are:

- 1 month
- 3 months
- 6 months
- 9 months
- 1 year
- 2 years
- Until space is needed
- Forever

Also, from Control Panel, you can cleanup old versions to make space.

Comment: Yes, but when you specify a storage period, Windows 10 won't keep your request very long. For example, I chose to back up daily and the "Until space is needed" option which Win 10 reset to "forever" soon after. So I have to re-do my choice once or twice a day.